# analytics event label is missing

Tags: google-analytics

I have problem with sending event to Google Analytics.
In some cases the event label is empty.
I can see the label in fiddler.

The category and action are always saved.
It seems as if it happens to label that are sent in low numbers.
Is there a limitation in Google analytics that it omits the label if the count to that label is relatively low and there is a lot of other traffic?
My site has a lot of traffic, millions of events per day

Comment: Would it be possible that your Event Label is longer than 500 bytes (not characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the number of data points crosses a certain threshold (depending on the report type) , GA uses [sampled data](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1042498) to reduce the load on their servers.

To see if a report is sampled, look for a checkerboard-like icon in the upper right corner of the interface. You can click this to access a slider to increase the amount of data in a sample, but only to a certain point.

Check to see if your reports are being sampled. If so, it may well be that a label with a small number of data points gets totally overlooked and therefore shows up as zero in the sampled report.

If this is indeed your problem, you can decrease the date range until you no longer see the sampling icon.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But I only see the checkerboard-like icon under event->Pages or event->overview and it is not the data I need. If I don’t see the icon does it mean that it is not sampled? It is a premium account. I will check the issue further

Comment: Premium accounts are unsampled as far as I know. Premium accounts come with a pretty good support package from Google (or the reseller, if applicable), so you may be able to direct this question to them for more hands-on support.

Comment: Although analytics did not show the yellow label about the sampled data when checking the events label, when I used the Unsampled Downloads, I did see the label

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in G4 they are now missing.
These are user fields (self made).
Also missing browser version. What a shame for Google.

[image]